# c# cant start a nginx

Tags: c#, nginx

I try to start a process(nginx) with this code:

```
 Process.Start(@"C:\nginx\nginx-1.9.5\nginx.exe");
```

The problem is it just not starting it.
If I start nginx.exe manually then it working fine.

Any idea why it not working and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm not find any problem in code. Try to paste exe from c# Code into "C:\nginx\nginx-1.9.5\" Execute It. if  its executes Then Problem was the file nginx.exe Requires Files In the path. then change working directory as "C:\nginx\nginx-1.9.5" Check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and finally solved it by changing the working directory to the folder that contains the `nginx.exe` file.

Try adding the following line to your code:

```
procInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\nginx\nginx-1.9.5";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using administrator privileges:

```
ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\nginx\nginx-1.9.5\nginx.exe");
procInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
procInfo.Verb = "runas";
Process.Start(procInfo);
```

Comment: Nginx just start and then automatic shut down.

Comment: Is there a document that opens with it? `Process.Start(@"C:\nginx\nginx-1.9.5\nginx.exe", yourFileName);`

Comment: I didnt understand ur question. Nginx(http://nginx.org/en/) is a web server like apache.